# Java InputStream NullPointerException with InputStream

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream

I've got two methods in a class:

```
  private static InputStream getSongStream(String ip, String id){
      try {
        URL url = new URL("http://"+ ip + "/" + Client.streamphp);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data); //Data is a simple Http Post that is know to work
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        return conn.getInputStream();

    } catch (MalformedURLException badurl) {
        System.out.println(badurl);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException noconnection) {
        System.out.println(noconnection);
        return null;
    }
  }

  public static void downloadSong(String ip, String id, String path){
      InputStream rd = Client.getSongStream(ip, id);
      try {
          OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));

          byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
          int len;
          while ((len = rd.read(buffer)) > 0) { //Here I get NullPointerException
             stream.write(buffer, 0, len);
          }
          stream.close();
          rd.close();

     } catch (IOException noconnection) {
          System.out.println(noconnection);
        }
  }
```

The line commented in the second method is the problem, if I put all in the same method I can download the song without problems, but not if I separate them.

Any ideas? I would like to have them separated to reuse getSongStream.

Comment: maybe rd is null... check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're swallowing exceptions in `getSongStream` and returning null. Don't do that - let the exception propagate up, possibly having wrapped it in another form... so declare that your method can throw (say) `IOException`. Your `downloadSong` method should probably declare that it can throw `IOException` too. Note that you should have finally blocks to make sure you close your streams appropriately even if an exception is thrown.

It's almost *always* a bad idea to catch an exception, write it out to standard output and then proceed as if everything is okay.